# Need a better way to make the function acts on adjacent elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a class A, a list of A instance(alist). Class A has an instance method (funca) that has only one parameter of another A instance and returns A instance.
Now I want to use "funca" to get the result of all the elements in "alist".
My script is like this:

```
b = a[0]
for a in alist[1:]:
    b=b.funca(a)
```

I feel the code is ugly. Is there a better way to do this? (iteration or something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially chaining the `A.funca()` calls based on the list, producing the call:

```
alist[0].funca(alist[1]).funca(alist[2]).funca(alist[3])...funca(alist[-1])
```

You could use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
from functools import reduce  # Python 3 compatibility
result = reduce(lambda a, b: a.funca(b), alist)
```

This essentially does the same as what your loop did, but in one line.

The `from functools import reduce` imports  the [function from the Python 3 location](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce); in Python 2 it is one of the built-in functions. From Python 2.6 onwards it is also available in the Python 3 location for forward compatibility.